# Flash security permissions not working in chrome

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, google-chrome

I just developed an application in Flex Action Script 3.it Runs Nicely on Firefox but Not in Chrome.When i Disable Pepper Flash Player Plugin It runs on chrome.Kindly Guide me How to tackle this Problem. I have spent 3 days for finding its solution but all my efforts are failed.

Comment: if we disable papper flash player then your app is running, am i right ?

Comment: yes correct. if I disable it then it works

Comment: According to the [patch notes](http://forums.adobe.com/message/6140488) it might have something to do with video buffers. Are you doing anything with video?

Comment: It worked now. :)
Problem was on html embed part. Some frame was set to visible false. that was not allowing to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who could be in possibly same problem,
It worked now. :) Problem was on html embed part. Some iframe was set to visible false. that was not allowing to click